# Were there cases of protesters starting violence at Trump rallies?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump

During the CNN GOP Debate, Donald Trump gave two explanations for the repeated violent reactions of some of his supporters to protests at Trump rallies. The first one being love for their country and anger at the current state of it, the second being this:

> We have some protesters who are bad dudes, they have done bad things. They are swinging. They are really dangerous and they get in there and they start hitting people, and we had a couple of big strong powerful guys doing damage to people. Not only the loudness — the loudness I don't mind — but doing serious damage.

There are others that dispute the claim that violence originated from protesters, see eg [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/03/11/donald-trumps-baffling-explanation-for-violence-at-his-campaign-rallies/).

Is there any evidence for cases where protesters at Trump rallies have gone in "swinging" and done "serious damage" **before** the CNN debate?

As there seems to be some confusion about the claim, please note: The question is about a specific statement Trump made. Trump made the statement in March about the *past*, not about future events which may or may not happen. It wouldn't make sense for Trump to justify assaults by his supporters with *future* assaults by protesters, so any events which happened *after* March 10th 2016 obviously do not support Trumps claim.

<sub>When I'm using "violence", I mean physical violence in the case of protesters as well as in the case of rally attendees.</sub>

<sub>A list of [violence by Trump supporters](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_slatest/2016/03/02/a_list_of_violent_incidents_at_donald_trump_rallies_and_events.html) can be found here (I haven't checked if it is complete). The earlier dates on that list are 10/01/2015, 10/02/2015, and 11/21/2015. As Trumps statement is meant as an explanation or defense of violence by his supporters, to verify the claim, an incident of a protester starting violence before 10/01/2015 would be great. Still, any events from before the CNN debate - which was on March the 10th - would help support his claim. This also means that the [person trying to jump the stage](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2016/03/13/trump-insists-isis-attacked-him-in-dayton-they-didn-t.html)  in Dayton or the [events in Chicago](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_slatest/2016/03/12/trump_blames_thugs_for_violence_at_chicago_rally.html) would not verify the claim, as they happened after the debate.</sub>

Comment: Isn't trying to disrupt a speech that people have come to hear a form of violence?

Comment: @jamesqf Thanks, I clarified the question. I mean physical violence, as that is obviously what Trump is referring to. Protests also don't necessarily try to disrupt a speech (they may eg only show signs, only chant when Trump isn't speaking, etc).

Comment: What are you asking here? If you find one case where protesters started being violent what will that tell you? If you find one case where Trump supporters started being violent (and there's plenty of stories claiming that) what will that tell you? One case of protesters starting violence doesn't really back up Trump's claim.

Comment: You might like to consider this case of [a Trump supporter assaulting a protester as he is being escorted from the rally by deputies.](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/trump-rally-assault-1.3486371)

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree, one case wouldn't really back up Trumps claim, as it is at least implied that this happens somewhat regularly, or that at least multiple people (`they`, `a couple`, etc) started acting (physically) violent (not in self defense). The notable claim here is that protesters start physically violent interactions at Trump rallies, so if there is evidence that this happens somewhat regularily, that would be a good answer. If there are notable sources that say that this doesn't happen, or that this only happened in a single instance, that would also be a good answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth And this isn't a question about violence from Trump supporters. That violence is well documented, and I don't think anyone doubts it, or the support Trump has given to these assault.

Comment: I find this kind of questions very very uninteresting...

Comment: Of more importance is whether violence is typical at any rally.

Comment: First, you say protesters, than you say supporters.  Which is it?

Comment: @KDog I'm not sure what is unclear. There were various documented cases of Trump supporters assaulting people at Trump rallies, and statements by Trump which seemed to support these assaults. When questioned about this, and asked if he feels responsible, Trump said that the violence by his supporters is in reaction to protesters assaulting people. But there does not seem to be any documentation backing up Trumps claim of protesters starting violence, hence the question.

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2016/03/13/us/politics/covering-donald-trump-and-witnessing-the-danger-up-close.html?_r=0  this might help